# In C, is the address of the first element in an array the same as the address of the array?

Tags: c

Consider this:

```
int i[50];
void *a = i; //i.e. = &i[0]
void *b = &i;
```

Will `a == b` always be true or are there platforms/compilers where this might not always be true ?

Answer (score 5):

yes, paragraph 6.5.9 of the standard (equality operator) says:

> Two pointers compare equal if ... both
>   are pointers to the same object
>   (including a pointer to an object and
>   a subobject at its beginning)

Comment: Sounds pretty convincing.  Just for completeness, are we safe to assume that an array element is counted as a subobject of the array?  (I've normally only considered the concept as applying to struct members.)

Comment: @Oli: arrays are defined as follows `An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a
particular member object type, called the element type`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the value cast to `void*` is the same ... but the original type isn't.

Having

```
int arr[100];
```

the value `arr`, when it decays to a pointer to its first element, has type `*int`;
the value `&arr` has type `int (*)[100]`

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, yes both a and b would be reported to be same, since the array in question is 1D. FYI - this does not hold true had it been a 2D or higher dimensional array in question? Read more about pointer to arrays,in that case. Good to know concept, though better avoided for maintaining good code readability.